# Can I run Selenium tests when hosts file does not have localhost alias?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am getting a "Bad request" exception when starting a test run with Selenium WebDriver in Firefox. I traced this problem to hosts config file (using Windows 7). The hosts file on my machine has this line (slightly edited, of course):

```
127.0.0.1 alias.set.by.security
```

This should be fixed by adding localhost to the line. The problem is, I cannot change this file, we have a security tool which depends on this and overrides my rights.
I found an issue related to this, https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3280

However, they are a bit misterious about how to use the fix. Does anybody know how to fix my code in order to make it work (it's not working as it is)?

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference(FirefoxProfile.ALLOWED_HOSTS_PREFERENCE, "localhost");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: which version of webdriver do you use? I don't see any problem while running selenium test even my host file entry does not have localhost value for 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Latest, 2.43.1. Working fine now with the code I put below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it was...obvious

```
profile.setPreference(FirefoxProfile.ALLOWED_HOSTS_PREFERENCE, "alias.set.by.security");
```